# How do I call out a class object?

Tags: python, class

I just currently finished making the game 'snake' as a practice to learn how to program, as I am new to programming for about 3 months.

Although the game is completed and runs the way I intended, I want to try to simplify my code and reduce the amount of lines as much as possible, and possibly make the script tidier as the current majority of my codes are cluster in the while loop.

Until now I haven't touched upon class objects, and I want everything in the while loop to go into individual classes that get called out from the `while` loop to reduce the amount of lines in it.

off-topic: by reading through the script, how else can I improve it to be run more efficiently, including simplifying some code as I may have over-complicated it?

I looked up how class object is used from w3school and other programming tutorials, but I still don't fully understand it as it only shows examples in using `print`. I did play around and experimented with class object examples and attempted to call them without using print, but I lack the knowledge of how to use them properly.

```
from graphics import *
from threading import Timer
import keyboard, random, time

# configurations
width = 400
gridHeight = width
height = 470
timer = False
game = True
score = 0
bonus = 0
x = 70
y = 30
radius = 10
length = radius * 2
playerLength = 3
poisonLength = playerLength
i = 0
k = 0
pointRadius = 5
points = False
cherryPoints = False
key = "Right"
countDown = 0

# set coordinations
cX = 90
cY = 30
coordX = [10]
coordY = [10]
while coordX[len(coordX)-1] != width-10:
    cX+=20
    coordX.append(cX)
while coordY[len(coordY)-1] != 390:
    cY+=20
    coordY.append(cY)
randomX = random.choice(coordX)
randomY = random.choice(coordY)
cherryRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
cherryRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
poisonRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
poisonRandomY = random.choice(coordY)

# window set up
win = GraphWin("SNAKE", width, height, autoflush = False)
win.setBackground(color_rgb(15,15,15))

# grid
lineX = 20
while lineX < width:
    gridX = Line(Point(lineX,0),Point(lineX,gridHeight))
    gridX.setOutline(color_rgb(25,25,25))
    gridX.draw(win)
    lineX += 20
lineY = 20
while lineY <= gridHeight:
    gridX = Line(Point(0,lineY),Point(width,lineY))
    gridX.setOutline(color_rgb(25,25,25))
    gridX.draw(win)
    lineY += 20

# snake banner
UI = Rectangle(Point(0,400),Point(width,height))
UI.setFill(color_rgb(102,51,0))
UI.setOutline(color_rgb(102,51,0))
UI.draw(win)
snakeTitle = Text(Point(width/2,420),"SNAKE")
snakeTitle.setTextColor("green")
snakeTitle.setSize(20)
snakeTitle.draw(win)
scoreTitle = Text(Point(320,424),"SCORE")
scoreTitle.setTextColor("white")
scoreTitle.setSize(10)
scoreTitle.draw(win)
scoreUI = Text(Point(320,435),score)
scoreUI.setTextColor("white")
scoreUI.setSize(10)
scoreUI.draw(win)

# make player
player = {}
player[0] = Rectangle(Point(x-20-radius,y-radius), Point(x-20+radius, y+radius))
player[1] = Rectangle(Point(x-40-radius,y-radius), Point(x-40+radius, y+radius))
player[2] = Rectangle(Point(x-60-radius,y-radius), Point(x-60+radius, y+radius))

# make poison
poison = {}

def main():
    global timer, scoreUI, score, bonus, playerLength, poisonLength, x, y, points, cherryPoints, randomX, randomY, cherryRandomX, cherryRandomY, poisonRandomX, poisonRandomY, key, countDown, k, game

    while(game==True):
        # score update
        scoreUI.undraw()
        scoreUI = Text(Point(320,435),score)
        scoreUI.setTextColor("white")
        scoreUI.setSize(10)
        scoreUI.draw(win)

        # generating new body blocks
        if len(player) < playerLength:
            i+=1
            player[i] = player[i-1].clone()

        # body following player
        player[0].undraw()
        for i in range(1,len(player)):
            player[len(player)-i].undraw()
            player[len(player)-i] = player[len(player)-i-1].clone()
            player[len(player)-i].draw(win)

        # update player's head coordinate
        player[0] = Rectangle(Point(x-radius,y-radius), Point(x+radius,y+radius))
        player[0].setFill("green")
        player[0].setWidth(2)
        player[0].draw(win)

        # player movement
        if keyboard.is_pressed("Up") and key != "Down":
            key = "Up"
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("Left") and key != "Right":
            key = "Left"
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("Down") and key != "Up":
            key = "Down"
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("Right") and key != "Left":
            key = "Right"
        if key == "Up":
            y -= length
        elif key == "Left":
            x -= length
        elif key == "Down":
            y += length
        elif key == "Right":
            x += length

        # point
        if points == False: # generates new point when eaten
            point = Rectangle(Point(randomX-pointRadius,randomY-pointRadius),Point(randomX+pointRadius,randomY+pointRadius))
            point.setFill("white")
            point.setWidth(2)
            point.draw(win)
            points = True
        if player[0].getCenter().getX() == point.getCenter().getX() and player[0].getCenter().getY() == point.getCenter().getY(): # when player eats the point
            point.undraw()
            playerLength += 1
            poisonLength += 1
            score += 200+bonus
            randomX = random.choice(coordX)
            randomY = random.choice(coordY)
            for i in range(len(player)):
                if (point.getCenter().getX() == player[i].getCenter().getX() and point.getCenter().getY() == player[i].getCenter().getY()) or (cherryPoints == True and cherryPoint.getCenter().getX() == point.getCenter().getX() and cherryPoint.getCenter().getY() == point.getCenter().getY()): # regenerate x and y coordinate if they share the same coordinate as player and cherry
                    randomX = random.choice(coordX)
                    randomY = random.choice(coordY)
            for i in range(len(poison)): # regenerate x and y coordinate if point shares the same coordinate to other array of poisons
                if point.getCenter().getX() == poison[i].getCenter().getX() and point.getCenter().getY() == poison[i].getCenter().getY():
                    cherryRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
                    cherryRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            points = False

        # cherry
        if countDown == 150:
            countDown = 0
            if cherryPoints == False: # generates new cherry from countdown
                cherryPoint = Rectangle(Point(cherryRandomX-pointRadius,cherryRandomY-pointRadius),Point(cherryRandomX+pointRadius,cherryRandomY+pointRadius))
                cherryPoint.setFill(color_rgb(213,0,50))
                cherryPoint.setWidth(2)
                cherryPoint.draw(win)
                cherryPoints = True
        if cherryPoints == True:
            for i in range(2, 6): # cherry blinks between countdown 40 to 100
                if countDown == 20*i:
                    cherryPoint.undraw()
                elif countDown == 10+(20*i):
                    cherryPoint.draw(win)
            if countDown >= 100: # when countdown becomes 100, remove cherry and reset count down
                cherryPoints = False
                countDown = 0
                cherryRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
                cherryRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
        if cherryPoints==True and player[0].getCenter().getX() == cherryPoint.getCenter().getX() and player[0].getCenter().getY() == cherryPoint.getCenter().getY(): # when player eats the cherry
            cherryPoint.undraw()
            score += 500
            cherryRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
            cherryRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            for i in range(len(player)):
                if (cherryPoint.getCenter().getX() == player[i].getCenter().getX() and cherryPoint.getCenter().getY() == player[i].getCenter().getY()) or (cherryPoint.getCenter().getX() == point.getCenter().getX() and cherryPoint.getCenter().getY() == point.getCenter().getY()): # regenerate x and y coordinate if they share the same coordinate as player and point
                    cherryRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
                    cherryRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            for i in range(len(poison)): # regenerate x and y coordinate if cherry shares the same coordinate to other array of poisons
                if cherryPoint.getCenter().getX() == poison[i].getCenter().getX() and cherryPoint.getCenter().getY() == poison[i].getCenter().getY():
                    cherryRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
                    cherryRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            cherryPoints = False

        # poison
        if poisonLength % 5 == 0: # generates a poison block each time the player size reaches the multiple of 5
            poison[k] = Rectangle(Point(poisonRandomX-pointRadius,poisonRandomY-pointRadius),Point(poisonRandomX+pointRadius,poisonRandomY+pointRadius))
            poison[k].setFill("green")
            poison[k].setWidth(2)
            poison[k].draw(win)
            poisonRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
            poisonRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            for i in range(len(player)):
                if (poison[k].getCenter().getX() == player[i].getCenter().getX() and poison[k].getCenter().getY() == player[i].getCenter().getY()) or (poison[k].getCenter().getX() == point.getCenter().getX() and poison[k].getCenter().getY() == point.getCenter().getY()) or (cherryPoints==True and poison[k].getCenter().getX() == cherryPoint.getCenter().getX() and poison[k].getCenter().getY() == cherryPoint.getCenter().getY()): # regenerate x and y coordinate if they share the same coordinate as player and point and cherry
                    poisonRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
                    poisonRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            for i in range(len(poison)):
                if poison[k].getCenter().getX() == poison[i].getCenter().getX() and poison[k].getCenter().getY() == poison[i].getCenter().getY(): # regenerate x and y coordinate if new poison shares the same coordinate to other array of poisons
                    poisonRandomX = random.choice(coordX)
                    poisonRandomY = random.choice(coordY)
            bonus+=50
            k+=1
            poisonLength+=1

        # game over requirements
        for i in range(len(poison)): # if player touches poison
            if player[0].getCenter().getX() == poison[i].getCenter().getX() and player[0].getCenter().getY() == poison[i].getCenter().getY():
                game = False
        for i in range(2, len(player)): # if player touches its own body or reach out of window
            if (player[0].getCenter().getX() == player[i].getCenter().getX() and player[0].getCenter().getY() == player[i].getCenter().getY()) or x < 0 or x > width or y < 0 or y > gridHeight:
                game = False

        # FPS
        update(10)
        countDown += 1


    # GAME OVER
    gameOver = Text(Point(width/2,200), "GAME OVER")
    gameOver.setTextColor("red")
    gameOver.setSize(30)
    gameOver.draw(win)
    update()
    time.sleep(2)
    win.close()

main()
```

Ideally the result should replace each code in the while loop with individual classes outside of the function to reduce the amount of lines in the main() function and make the script easier to read.

Comment: Instead of writing a class you should maybe consider writing a function?

Comment: +1 to what @Nils said above about the functions. It can better organize your code and make it more readable. The function name should be self-describing so when a reader sees the name, they know what it does right away.
As for classes, they are used when you want to create an instance of something in which you can maintain the state of it. For example, you can have a ```Player``` class that keeps track of the player's length throughout the game. Check out the Python docs to learn more about that: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: Two users said it and I say it again: Use functions. And when you do that do it as you should do. Forget `global` and use parameters and return values.

Comment: [codereview.se] is the appropriate place to ask for help in improving code that already works.

Comment: I read the comments and tried to change them into function(), but I am already struggling. I don't understand how to put the parameters and return values into the the functions and connect them together. Perhaps I am missing something and I should go back to learn how to use function properly?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are essentially just bundles of code that contain various attributes and methods.

A `Snake` class might have a list of coordinates for each section of the body (the first is the head).

```py
class Snake:

  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.positions = [(x, y)]

  def get_head(self):
    return self.positions[0]

  def move_forward(self):
    self.positions.pop()
    self.positions.insert(0, self.get_head()[1] + 1)

  def move_backward(self):
    self.positions.pop()
    self.positions.insert(0, self.get_head()[1] - 1)

  ...
```

And so on. Classes, at this level, let you think of objects as concrete entities, distinct from each other but easily manipulated.